# Two way replication

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have a little problem...

I have this case:

- 2 server instances
- 2 Databases
- 1 Table (5 columns)

From **server 1** I created publication to replicate all columns of tables I have in **DB1**.

From **server 2** I created subscription to pull all columns from tables which is in **DB1**.

But now, I need to publish a column of the same table from **server 2** to **server 1** and also it has to be in same DB...

I tried with using logic and creating publication for **server 2** and subscription on **server 1** but there is error appearing:

> You have selected the Publisher as a Subscriber and entered a
>   subscription database that is the same as the publishing database.
>   Select another subscription database.

```
I need it to be A to B and B to A replication
```

I hope someone understood my problem and have an answer for me.

p.s. Ask for more info if you need ...

Comment: Merge or Transactional?

Comment: Actually I Don`t know, I`m new in replications so you can make me advice...

Comment: I used transactional

Comment: but I read somewhere that Merge is better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description it seems as if you require bidirectional replication.  You may want to consider using Merge Replication, Bidirectional Transactional Replication, or Peer-to-Peer Replication.

I suggest reading through [Selecting the Appropriate Type of Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152565.aspx) to see what type of replication best meets your application requirements.

Comment: Peer-To-Peer is only for enterprise users, I need it for some cheaper versions of SQL Server 2000/2005 or 2008 (the best will be for 2008)

Is there any link where I can see "Step By Step" how to setup bidirectional replication? Something without using too much TSQL, just with wizards (like standard one direction replication) ??

Comment: You cannot setup Bidirectional Transactional Replication using the Wizard, T-SQL only.  You can setup Transactional Publication with updatable subscriptions in SQL Server 2008 using the Wizards; note: this feature is deprecated in 2012 and should be avoided. You are correct, Peer-to-Peer is Enterprise edition only. I believe you will want to use Merge as it is available in Standard edition and can be done through the Wizards. With Merge, articles are bidirectional by default and can also be set as download-only if required.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams, +1 for Appropriate selection for replication.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a step-by-step guide on implementing bi-directional transactional replication.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820675)

This should meet your requirements based on the following MSDN description:

> For example, if you have two servers (Server A and Server B), the
>   servers are said to be in bidirectional transactional replication if
>   both of the following conditions are true:
>
> The changes that are made
>   to Table T1 at Server A are replicated to Table T1 at Server B.
>
> The changes that are made to Table T1 at Server B are replicated to Table
>   T1 at Server A.

However, this isn't simple to implement or to maintain, and it won't be possible to properly manage it without using T-SQL; the SSMS GUI is often deficient in what it allows you to do.

Are you sure that you need to use replication?  A simpler solution would be ideal... maybe a Sql Server agent job would suffice, or maybe even an SSIS package?

Comment: Is there any better (free) solution I can use to connect two servers and sync them everytime I want (or scheduled) ??

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use SSIS or T-SQL to perform the sync.  Simple and free.  If you're not comfortable with writing the necessary T-SQL to do this, then I wouldn't recommend attempting the same thing using any form of replication, because this would be much more complex than writing the necessary insert, update, and delete commands to perform the sync.